# How create generic WSDL that consume another WSDL?

Tags: php, web, service, wsdl

I'm trying to create a generic WSDL with the goal to add or connect / communicate other WSDL to have a single unified web service.
Is it possible to do this?
What I could do is a web service that in one of its functions calls or instantiates a client from another WS and returns the data as if it were running a normal client to that URL.
The issue I'm noticing now is that the response times are tripled for each request the generic WS performs to said URL.

Is there any way to implement this in a better way? good practices?

I want to do it this way for a topic of confidentiality of the service, for this reason I can not directly access the URL.

In the technical aspect said WSDL I did it with PHP using the lib *nu_soap*

Any suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding the question. What do you mean by connecting to other WSDL? You want the same WSDL contract for different webservices or you want a generic websevice to take all requests and the call some other web services?

Comment: I need to create a generic web services in which I can join other web services.
To put an example in the generic ws I call the function queryName and I pass a parameter name, but the function consultName is a client that calls another web service to pass the parameter: name, when I receive the answer formatting the data and the I show on the screen. My question was if I have a way to improve this process because the response times are doubled.